# c- Seg fault during object_list_print() function?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

---

FIXED: I added a quick if statement before changing the pointers address

---

My program is seg faulting on the line:

```
obj = (object_t *) model->objs->current->entity;
```

in my object_list_print() function, which looks like this.

```
// does not call object_print() directly, but instead
// will call the polymorphic function obj->printer() 
void object_list_print(model_t  *model, FILE  *out)
{
   object_t *obj;

   /* For each object in model->objs 
           list, assert that it is an object, 
                then invoke polymorphic printer    */
   list_reset(model->objs);
   obj = (object_t *)model->objs->current->entity;

   while(list_not_end(model->objs))
   {
      assert(obj->cookie == OBJ_COOKIE);
      obj->printer(obj, out);
      list_next_link(model->objs);
           // ADDED LINE //
      if(list_not_end(model->objs))         /* This line fixes the code */
         obj = (object_t *)model->objs->current->entity;  /* SEG FAULTS */
   }

   return;
}
```

For reference, model->objs is a list_t structure

```
typedef struct list_type
{
   link_t  *first;           /* First link in the list */
   link_t  *last;            /* Last link in the list  */
   link_t  *current;
}  list_t;
```

and each link_t looks like this:

```
typedef struct link_type
{
   struct link_type *next;    /* Next link in the list   */
   void             *entity;  /* Entity owned by link    */
}  link_t;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: There's no need to cast `void*` like that in C.  One of these is a bad pointer: `model->objs->current`. Use your debugger.

Comment: @EdS. If one of those were a bad pointer, it should have given a warning on the earlier line. I've gone over the structures, and each of the pointers are correct.   
model_t contains a list_t *objs, (pointer to a list). The list_t and link_t structures are above.

Comment: " If one of those were a bad pointer, it should have given a warning on the earlier line" - why do you believe that?  Please link to the relevant part of the specification which says that the compiler must omit a diagnostic in the case of a potentially "bad" pointer (hint; it doesn't exist.)  One of them is certainly _not_ "correct" if you're getting a segfault.  Don't assume that your code is correct when it obviously is not.